# VNC keystrokes not sending to remote desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc

I'm using TightVNC to connect from my work computer (Fedora) to my home desktop (Windows 7).

For some reason when I attempt to type in the remote desktop (vnc viewer) the keystrokes aren't sending to my home desktop.

Anyone have any ideas as to why this is and/or how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to have VNC in "read-only" mode.  Have you checked that?  When "read-only", no input events (keyboard or mouse) are transmitted to the remote end.

Comment: didn't work for me: my MOUSE control IS getting to the server; KEYSTOKES are not.  Client: RealVNC client 6.0 on Windows; server: tightvncserver on Ubuntu 14.04.  I've checked my client config; the settings are similar to connections where keystrokes are correctly sent...

Answer (score 2):

If you typed in the password twice on the TightVNC server, then you didn't confirm the password, you set the read-only password to be the same as the access password. Guess which one takes precedence when logging in (I've done this to myself a few times...)?

Comment: I checked this; wan't my issue. (My mouse control IS getting through, just not my keystrokes.)  What could cause that?